# Highcharts.js - placing text into the center of donut

Tags: css, highcharts

I am trying to place some text into the center of highcharts.js donut element, but no success after two hours of research. Looks like some simple css will do the job, but can't figure out the right syntax. Help please !!!

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e44mb6fu/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#order_suggestions_graph_by_vendor').highcharts({
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        innerSize: '60%'
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      y: 40
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Browser share',
      innerSize: '50%',
      data: [
        ['Firefox', 10.38],
        ['IE', 56.33],
        ['Chrome', 24.03],
        ['Safari', 4.77],
        ['Opera', 0.91], {
          name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
          y: 0.2,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }]

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="order_suggestions_graph_by_vendor"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently pushing the title down by 40px. To not do this, simply set the `y` position offset to 0:

```
title: {
  text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
  align: 'center',
  verticalAlign: 'middle',
  y: 40 // change this to 0
}
```

[Amended JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e44mb6fu/1/).

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan I've slightly changed my answer. This applies to both the old JSFiddle and the new one.

Comment: Well, there's seems to be some issue yet :( http://jsfiddle.net/g4tb1z7c/

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan you've not set `y` to `0`. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/g4tb1z7c/1/

Comment: It is vertically centered, but horizontal alignment is still not centered

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan I'm not sure what the issue is, it looks both vertically and horizontally centred for me (Chrome v53).

Comment: Yes, you're right. The issue now is in browser. In IE, it's perfectly centralized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125696/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-james-donnelly).

Comment: This no longer works. The title isn't exactly vertically centered.